# Kill a QProcess running in a different QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qprocess

I have a class that inherits `QThread` and I reimplemented the `run()` method. In this run method, there's a `QProcess` (declared in run) that starts a program.

Now if I close my application while that process is still running, it actually won't close until the process finishes.

So my question is how do I stop this process ?

From what I've read in Qt docs, I cannot use signal/slot here since my process will have thread affinity with a thread that is not the main thread, so the connections are queued and this doesn't stop my process.

I'm using Qt 5.8

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: here's the thread code, let me know if you need more

```
void run()
{
    QString cmd;
    QProcess p;

    connect(&p, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(quit()));
    //connect(this, SIGNAL(signalTerminateProcess()), &p, SLOT(kill())); // queued connect that doesn't kill my process

    p.start(cmd);
    if(p.waitForFinished(-1))
    {
        qInfo("process done");
    }
}
```

Comment: show the thread code.

Comment: Why do you use a thread to execute a process if you can use the QProcess signals in a simple way?

Comment: Because there are two cases inside my run function, and one of them cannot be done with a QProcess, but I decided to keep both parts in this QThread class

Comment: You could try with connect(this,SIGNAL(finished()), &p , SLOT(close()))

Comment: With the code that you show, if you stop the process the thread is terminated. Use QProcess::kill()

Comment: But i don't know how to stop the process, things I've tried didn't work

Comment: You have  `p` member of the class, and create a slot to call if you want to stop, and then in the slot calls `p.kill();`

Comment: I don't think I can declare the process as a member of the thread class, because I would get the message "cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread". Since run() is executed in a thread which is different than the one where p would be declared (if it was a member of the thread class)

Comment: It shows a complete code, in the code that you see I see QProcess create it inside run().

Comment: Yes the QProcess is created inside run(), but I don't get your previous comment then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can use signal & slots across QThreads and you can even wait for the slot to be executed using `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`. See [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads).

However, this requires the target QObject to live in a thread that has a running event loop. In your case, since you have overloaded `QThread::run()`, you will not have an event loop.

As I see it, you have 2 ways of fixing your code either you do a small fix or you change the design and use the event loop.

## 1. Quick fix

```
void run()
{
    QString cmd;
    QProcess p;

    connect(&p, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(quit()));
    //connect(this, SIGNAL(signalTerminateProcess()), &p, SLOT(kill())); // queued connect that doesn't kill my process

    p.start(cmd);
    while(! p.waitForFinished(100)) //Wake up every 100ms and check if we must exit
    {
        if (QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested())
        {
            p.terminate();
            if (! p.waitForFinished(1000))
                p.kill()
            break;
        }
    }
    qInfo("process done");
}

int cleanUp()
{
    thread->requestInterruption();
    thread->wait();
}
```

or

```
QProcess *process = nullptr;
void run()
{
    QString cmd;
    QProcess p;
    process = &p; //You shouldn't do that in real code

    connect(&p, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(quit()));
    //connect(this, SIGNAL(signalTerminateProcess()), &p, SLOT(kill())); // queued connect that doesn't kill my process

    p.start(cmd);
    while(! p.waitForFinished(100)) //Wake up every 100ms and check if we must exit
    {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    }
    qInfo("process done");
    process = nullptr;
}

int cleanUp()
{
    QTimer::singleShot(0, process, &QProcess::terminate);
    // Qt 5.10 -> QMetaObject::invokeMethod(process, &QProcess::terminate);
    if (! thread->wait(1000))
    {
        QTimer::singleShot(0, process, &QProcess::kill);
        thread->wait();
    }
}
```

## 2. Event loop fix

```
// Create thread
QThread thread;
thread.start();

// Create process and move it to the other thread
QProcess process;
process.moveToThread(&thread);

void startProcess()
{
    p.start(cmd);
}

QMutex mutex;
void stopProcess()
{
    p.terminate();
    if (!p.waitForFinished(1000))
        p.kill();
    p.moveToThread(qApp->thread());
    mutex.unlock();
}

// Call startProcess() in the other thread
QTimer::singleShot(0, &process, &startProcess);

// Call stopProcess() in the other thread
mutex.lock();
QTimer::singleShot(0, &process, &stopProcess);
mutex.lock();

thread.quit();
if (!thread.wait(100))
    thread.terminate();
```

You can :

- Replace the mutex by using an atomic or using signals connected with `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`.
- Replace `startProcess()` and `stopProcess()` by slots and lambdas.
- Replace calls to `QTimer::singleShot()` by `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` or by using signals. *Note thate you can use `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` with `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`*

Comment: Hi Benjamin, went for your first fix, worked great tahnks !
Somehow google always showed me QThread doc page from Qt 4.8 and requestInterruption() wasn't a thing back then, so I missed it.